# Add custom SVG icons to Social Icon MENU in WordPress Twenty Seventeen Child Theme

Tags: menus, child-theme, icon, theme-twenty-seventeen, svg

I'm having trouble **[adding custom SVG icons to the Social Icon Menu in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/345603/add-custom-svg-icons-to-social-icon-menu-in-wordpress-twenty-seventeen-child-the)** Twentyseventeen Child Theme.The menu works fine with all pre-packaged SVGs included with the theme, but I can't add custom SVGs to the child theme.

Here's what I've done so far to add the **"Etsy" SVG** to the Social Icons Menu:

- Copy the `/assets/img/svg-icons.svg` file into the child theme
- Pasted the [Etsy SVG's](https://simpleicons.org) path into the `svg-icons.svg` file with all the other icons

[image: Screenshot adding Etsy SVG path to the svg-icons.svg file in WordPress TwentySeventeen child theme]

- Copy the `/inc/icon-functions.php` file into the child theme
- Add 'etsy.com' to the array of social media sites

[image: Adding etsy.com to the array of social media sites registered with the twentyseventeen_social_links_icons() function]

- Then I "called" the `/inc/icon-functions.php` at the bottom of the child theme's `functions.php`

[image: add icon-functions.php to the functions.php file]

This didn't work. WordPress Core recommended using the `get_template_part` function in [New WordPress Functions and Hook Behaviors for WordPress4.7](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/09/09/new-functions-hooks-and-behaviour-for-theme-developers-in-wordpress-4-7/), but I've also tried:

- `get_theme_file_uri()`
- `get_theme_file_path()`
- `get_template_directory()`
- `get_template_directory_uri()`
- `get_stylesheet_directory()`
- `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`

All to no avail. The only thing that displays on the site is the "broken link" icon.

I also tried using **require** instead of *include* but this threw a 505 error and said "Site Down For Maintenance"

All caches cleared. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

These articles reference very similar issues but none of them solved mine in particular:

- [Implementing only custom SVGs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291675/how-to-implement-my-own-icons-instead-of-using-the-svg-icon-system)
- [Add custom SVG icons to social nav menu](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-custom-svg-icons-to-social-nav-menu/)
- [Add custom social icon to Twenty Seventeen](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-custom-social-icon-to-twenty-seventeen/)
- [How to customize social link menu in WordPress](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LC0s5YYQG6E)
- [How to add SVG to WordPress](https://themeisle.com/blog/add-svg-to-wordpress/)
- [SVG Custom Icon Files](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/svg-custom-icon-files/)
- [Adding SVG Icons and Graphics to WordPress Theme](https://jackiedelia.com/adding-svg-icons-graphics-wordpress-theme/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to copy the `inc/icon-functions.php` file and `include`/`require` it from the child theme — remember that the parent theme will also load the same file/functions and that would result in a PHP error if you did not rename the functions in the copied file.

So try these:

1. *(You've already done this properly, as I could see it. But just for completeness, I included this step.)* Copy the SVG file (`assets/images/svg-icons.svg`) to your child theme and paste the [Etsy's SVG](https://simpleicons.org/icons/etsy.svg) `path` to that `svg-icons.svg` file.

   ```
   <!-- In wp-content/themes/your-theme/assets/images/svg-icons.svg -->
   <symbol id="icon-etsy" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
   <path ...></path>
   </symbol>
   ```
2. Copy the `twentyseventeen_include_svg_icons()` function to your child theme `functions.php` file, then *rename the function*. Unhook `twentyseventeen_include_svg_icons` from `wp_footer`, then hook the renamed function to `wp_footer`:

   ```php
   function my_theme_include_svg_icons() {
       // Define SVG sprite file.
       $svg_icons = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/assets/images/svg-icons.svg';

       // If it exists, include it.
       if ( file_exists( $svg_icons ) ) {
           require_once( $svg_icons );
       }
   }
   remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'twentyseventeen_include_svg_icons', 9999 );
   add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_theme_include_svg_icons', 9999 );
   ```
3. Use the `twentyseventeen_social_links_icons` hook to add the Etsy icon to the icons array:

   ```php
   add_filter( 'twentyseventeen_social_links_icons', function ( $icons ) {
       $icons['etsy.com'] = 'etsy';
       return $icons;
   } );
   ```

Save the theme functions file, reload your browser's cache (if necessary) and check if the Etsy's icon now appearing as expected. ( It should, though.. :) )

And BTW, you don't have to save the SVG file in `assets/images`, but for testing purposes, just use that default path.

Also, make sure your Social Links Menu has a menu item with `etsy.com` in the link URL. But you can also manually display the 'E' symbol like so:

```php
echo twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'etsy', 'title' => __( 'Testing Etsy symbol', 'my-theme' ) ) );
```

Comment: The function didn't work as it was written in the parent theme, but yours worked perfectly as you typed it. Where your function has "get_stylesheet_directory()", the parent theme function uses "get_parent_theme_file_path". Regardless, it worked, thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that your child theme should use `get_stylesheet_directory()` and not `get_parent_theme_file_path()`.. :)