# Trying to add a custom social icon to a Twenty Twenty-One child theme

Tags: menus, hooks, child-theme, theme-twenty-twenty-one

I am trying to add an icon to the Twenty Twenty-One social icons, but having trouble registering it.

[This support article](https://wordpress.org/support/article/twenty-twenty-one/#site-logo) refers to a [Themes field guide for WordPress 5.5](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/30/themes-field-guide-wordpress-5-5/) which gives instructions on how to add a custom icon and hook it in so that it appears when the relevant url is typed in as a menu item custom link.

I copied the function from the Field Guide, changing the hook to match 2021 theme rather than 2020 (since the hook in `twentytwentyone/classes/class-twenty-twenty-one-svg-icons.php` is `twenty_twenty_one_svg_icons_social`).

Here are the functions I added to functions.php: (apologies -- including full svg vectors in case they are causing the error)

```
function mychildtheme_twenty_twenty_one_social_icons_map( $icons ) {
    $icons['rhs-calendar'] = array(
        'rhs-1.test',
        'rhs-1.test/events/list/',
    );

    return $icons;
}
add_filter( 'twenty_twenty_one_social_icons_map', 'mychildtheme_twenty_twenty_one_social_icons_map' );

// add the calendar icon
function mychildtheme_twenty_twenty_one_svg_icons_social( $icons ) {
    $icons['rhs-calendar'] = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M 6.75,0 C 7.1642136,0 7.5,0.33578644 7.5,0.75 V 3 h 9 V 0.75 c 0,-0.99999957 1.5,-0.99999957 1.5,0 V 3 h 2.75 c 0.966,0 1.75,0.784 1.75,1.75 v 16 c 0,0.966498 -0.783502,1.75 -1.75,1.75 H 3.25 C 2.2835017,22.5 1.5,21.716498 1.5,20.75 v -16 C 1.5,3.784 2.284,3 3.25,3 H 6 V 0.75 C 6,0.33578644 6.3357864,0 6.75,0 Z M 21,7.9375 H 3 V 20.75 C 3,20.888 3.112,21 3.25,21 h 17.5 C 20.888071,21 21,20.888071 21,20.75 Z" id="path833"/>
      <path d="m 7.2944571,17.386715 h 4.1851359 v 1.803463 H 4.9127844 v -0.743412 q 0,-0.75718 0.2546876,-1.356039 0.2546875,-0.605744 0.6401605,-1.080702 0.3854731,-0.481841 0.8397806,-0.846664 0.4611909,-0.371706 0.8741978,-0.667694 0.4336571,-0.309755 0.7571791,-0.591976 0.3304055,-0.282222 0.5506758,-0.55756 0.2271538,-0.282221 0.3372889,-0.564442 0.1101352,-0.289105 0.1101352,-0.612627 0,-0.633277 -0.3579393,-0.956799 -0.3579392,-0.323522 -1.0944681,-0.323522 -1.2734377,0 -2.4367402,1.011866 V 9.9870092 q 1.2872046,-0.8328971 2.9048146,-0.8328971 0.7502958,0 1.3422722,0.19962 0.5988599,0.1927365 1.0118669,0.5575592 0.413007,0.3648227 0.626394,0.8879647 0.22027,0.516258 0.22027,1.156419 0,0.681461 -0.213387,1.211487 -0.206503,0.530025 -0.557559,0.963682 -0.344173,0.433657 -0.7984801,0.79848 Q 9.4696264,15.287263 8.9809016,15.624552 8.6504962,15.85859 8.3407411,16.092627 8.0378694,16.31978 7.8038322,16.546934 7.569795,16.767205 7.432126,16.980591 7.2944571,17.193978 7.2944571,17.386715 Z" />
    <path d="m 12.97644,18.93549 v -1.85853 q 1.011866,0.61951 2.154518,0.61951 0.860431,0 1.342273,-0.406123 0.488724,-0.413007 0.488724,-1.115119 0,-1.466174 -2.071917,-1.466174 -0.764063,0 -1.762163,0.117018 l 0.371707,-5.5067572 h 5.224536 v 1.7759292 h -3.565626 l -0.137669,1.975549 q 0.530026,-0.0413 0.915499,-0.0413 1.521242,0 2.381672,0.79848 0.860431,0.79848 0.860431,2.147635 0,1.493708 -1.025633,2.443624 -1.025634,0.943032 -2.780913,0.943032 -1.424873,0 -2.395439,-0.426774 z"/>
    </svg>';
    return $icons;
}

add_filter( 'twenty_twenty_one_svg_icons_social', 'mychildtheme_twenty_twenty_one_svg_icons_social' );
```

The new functions and filters throw this error:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'v' in C:\laragon\www\rhs-1\wp-content\themes\twentytwentyone\
classes\class-twenty-twenty-one-svg-icons.php on line 243
```

The relevant line in `class-twenty-twenty-one-svg-icons.php`:

```
242 foreach ( $regex_map as $icon => $regex ) {
243         if ( preg_match( $regex, $uri ) ) {
244             return self::get_svg( 'social', $icon, $size ) . '<span class="screen-reader-text">';
245         }
246     }
```

Now, the instructions in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/345842/143329) include the icon in the "icons_map" function in a completely different way, should I be doing it like that?

Secondly, per that answer, I'm not sure I understand if and why I would have to unhook the parent theme social icons?

Third, am I pushing my luck if I also want to use this icon in the Gutenberg "Social Icons" block, or is there some other way to include the social icons (secondary) menu as a Gutenberg block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/345842) was written in 2019, yet the new [field guide](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/30/themes-field-guide-wordpress-5-5/) ("Adding icons in Twenty Twenty") was written about a year later (2020), so you should just use that new field guide, and in response to the main issue:

> I am trying to add an icon to the Twenty Twenty-One social icons, but
> having trouble registering it.

You're getting the `preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'v'` error because of the unescaped `/` (slash) as in `rhs-1.test/events/list/` which you supplied via the `twenty_twenty_one_social_icons_map` filter.

And unfortunately, there's no way to escape it correctly because the function which applies the filter calls `preg_quote()`, so back-slashes (`\`) will be escaped. Also, just so you know, the `/` is *not* escaped because `preg_quote()` is called without the second parameter specified. [(see source on Trac)](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentytwentyone/1.3/classes/class-twenty-twenty-one-svg-icons.php#L238)

However, the values in the array (`$icons['rhs-calendar']`) should actually be just domains, subdomains and/or IPs like `example.com` and `foo.example2.com`, e.g. `array( 'example.com', '127.0.0.1' )`. And if you added a domain/IP there, then all URLs with that very domain/IP would use your custom icon, so there's no need to specify a URL path like the `rhs-1.test/events/list/`.

---

> I also want to use this icon in the Gutenberg "Social Icons" block

As of writing, the core Social Icons block does not provide any PHP or JS filters that we could use to *easily* add custom icons to the default list (and note that the Social Icons block is a dynamic block and it also has its own editor script), but you could alternatively create a block that would add your custom icon to the editor. However, you would need to ask in another question for more details on that.

Or another option is, add your custom icon using the Link block via the Social Icons block, then set a custom CSS class for the icon, and just style the button accordingly:

1. Save your icon's SVG as `assets/images/rhs-calendar.svg` in your child theme folder (e.g. at `wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone-child`).
2. Add this to your editor style file (`assets/css/style-editor.css`):

   ```css
   .wp-block-social-link.rhs-calendar-icon > button {
       background-image: url(../images/rhs-calendar.svg);
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: center;
       background-size: 24px;
       width: 36px;
       height: 36px;
   }

   .wp-block-social-link.rhs-calendar-icon > button > svg {
       display: none;
   }
   ```
3. Add this to your main `style.css` file, or wherever you want, just ensure the styles are applied *on the front-end side* of the site:

   ```css
   .wp-social-link.rhs-calendar-icon > a {
       background-image: url(assets/images/rhs-calendar.svg);
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: center;
       background-size: 24px;
       width: 36px;
       height: 36px;
   }

   .wp-social-link.rhs-calendar-icon > a > svg {
       display: none;
   }
   ```
4. Add the icon using the Link block.

   [image]
5. Set the custom icon class via the "Additional CSS class(es)" field.

   [image]

### Additional Notes

1. There's an unwanted `</g>` tag in your SVG code.
2. In my SVG file (`rhs-calendar.svg`), I removed the `sodipodi:nodetypes="ssccsscsssssssscssccssssc"`..

Comment: Very greatly appreciated!
For your "Social Icons" block instructions, I edited step 2; the url needed `assets` for me. 
On my project, I had to add styling slightly differently to the custom icon, because it is a `background-image` and therefore misses some of the classes: modified `background-size`, `width`, and `height` to match "Large" size picked in the social icons Gutenberg block editor; added `filter: invert(100%) brightness(100%) contrast(100%);` to match custom color settings applied to other icons.